# Loopback afterRemote method on routes with relation

Tags: node.js, loopback

I'm struggling to add an afterRemote method to one of my end points in Loopback

I have two models : `Customer` and `Bills`.

A Customer `has many` Bills.
So Loopback created the /api/Customer/{id}/bills for me (Get route)

I'd like to change the response of that route but I can't figure out how to access it with a afterRemote method.

For accessing the Get route of Customer Model, I write :

```
Customer.afterRemote("find", function(ctx, next){SOME METHOD});
```

... and it works well.

I tried to write this for accessing Customer/{id}/bills :

```
Customer.afterRemote("__findById__bills", function(ctx, next){SOME METHOD});
```

But this does not work, despite the documentation (https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Accessing-related-models.html).

Anyone could help me on that matter ?

Thanks !

M.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out the solution. The syntax is :

```
Customer.afterRemote("*___get__bills", function(ctx, next){SOME METHOD});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy way to get method's name. Open loopback explorer, open any models route and check the url. You can see the method name in the end of url. Replace one underline with double underlines. In your case it's better to write through prototype not with asterisk.

Example:

Url: localhost:3000/explorer/#!/Accounts_prototype_get_crews

Name of the method for the hook : prototype.__get__crews